# How to override a Model field without saving in Django

Tags: python, django

Suppose I have a model below :

```
class Post(MainProcess, TimeStampedModel, SoftDeletionModel, models.Model):

    """Post model."""
    slug = models.SlugField(default=uuid.uuid4(), unique=True, max_length=100)
    uuid = models.UUIDField(unique=True, max_length=500,
                            default=uuid.uuid4,
                            editable=False,
                            db_index=True, blank=False, null=False)
    title = models.CharField(_('Title'), max_length=100, blank=False,
                             null=False)
    image = models.ImageField(_('Image'), upload_to='blog_images', null=True,
                              max_length=900, blank=True)
```

I wanted to override the `image` field values without using the `save()` function, what is the best approach here which will be efficient.

Comment: What do you mean by "override"? Do you want to change the values in the database?

Comment: Hi @lain, yes I want to do that

Comment: The most appropriate method involves using `save()`, why exactly do you not want to use it?

Comment: I wanted to some dynamic concatenation

Comment: Can you update the question with an example of this dynamic concatenation and whatever code you currently have.